# TIMESAT3.3 output errors

Tags: remote-sensing, timesat

When I ran "fit2img" in TIMESAT3.3,I got problematic result image.Contrasted with original image, this result image seemed to be cut into two parts and was badly deformed.I did not know what happened.Have you ever been encountered this kind of problem?I am very puzzled.
[image: fitting result image]
[image: original image]

Answer (score 0):

Your issue might be that you've put the wrong number of rows or columns, or that you've chosen the wrong endianness.